# When to use bind and when to use delegate in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am interested in knowing when bind function should be used and when delegate function should be used in jquery. Do they not perform the same functionalites? What is the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use `bind` (or better yet, `on`, as `bind` is deprecated; noted by @Yoshi) when you have a few, *existing* elements you want to bind event listeners to. You use `delegate` when the elements you want to handle do not exist yet (e.g. they are dynamically generated and you don't want to bind handlers to each new element you create, but they have a common parent you can put the delegate on), or when you're handling events on a lot of elements with a common parent (which is more efficient with a delegate on the parent than with individual handlers on each element).

DOM events *bubble* up the DOM hierarchy, so when you click on an element `onclick` handlers for that element are triggered, then handlers on its parent, then its parent, and so on (unless a handler calls `stopPropagation` on the event, which cancels the further bubbling up. When you use `bind`/`on`, you attach your handler to the specific element you want to handle, and it is triggered directly by the target you've set it up on; when you use `delegate`, a jQuery internal handler is attached to the element you specify, and it catches the event on its way up the bubble chain; jQuery then checks if the actual target (which is a child of the element the handler is attached to) matches the selector you've specified with the delegation, and if it is it is invoked (it is called as if your actual handler was attached to the target element and not the parent element; noted by @shannon).

Comment: A note that [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) is now preferred before both methods would be nice.

Comment: Note that delegate is applied to a parent element, but the event is called *as though* it were on the child element that triggered it. Also note that with delegate, you have to ensure that not only do *descendants* of the element you are interested in not eat the event before you act on it, but also any elements between that element and the ancestor the delegate was applied to.

Comment: @Yoshi why is on preferred to the other two methods?

Comment: `on` actually combines the functionality of `bind` and `delegate`; if you pass an additional selector, it acts as `delegate`, otherwise it acts as `bind` ([reference to jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/)). `bind` and `delegate` are deprecated only because `on` is a more concise interface to the same functionality, `on` is not any _better_ than them in terms of final result. Being deprecated, relying on `bind` or `delegate` means you'll need to revise all your code when they are removed from a future version of jQuery.